# HQl query of sql query?

Tags: sql, mapping, hql

Following is a sql query and i want hql query for the same ??any suggestions would be appreciated.!

in this query am trying to fetch records of two tables 'blogs' and 'askquestions' which are not mapped with eachother.

```
  SELECT blog_title as title ,created_date as date FROM  blog  UNION SELECT ask_question as title , created_on as date FROM askquestions ) as aa ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately HQL does not support `UNION`, `UNION ALL` as of yet.

You could still try the following work around:

```
// Create two query strings for two sub HQLs
String firstHQLQueryStr = " from blog b where <criteria1>";
String secondHQLQueryStr = "from askquestions a where <criteria2>";

// Divide the two select clauses into two sub HQLs
Query query1 = session.createQuery(firstHQLQueryStr);
Query query2 = session.createQuery(secondHQLQueryStr);

// Fetch the data from database using these two sub HQLs first
List firstDataList= query1.list();
List secondDataList= query2.list();

//Combine the results
firstDataList.add(secondDataList);

// Collection equivalent to UNION ALL
List nonUniqueCollection =  firstDataList;

//Collection equivalent to Union (as non-unique elements are removed)
HashSet uniqueCollection = new HashSet(nonUniqueCollection );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i think in this way it is not possible because i want to print the list according to date(Date column exists in both tables).And the latest one must be printed first and the remaining  later.

Comment: well true, then there is no other alternative unfortunately, since its not yet added as a support in HQL. And this has also been raised [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1050).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
select * from ((blog_title as title ,created_date as date FROM  blog) union (SELECT ask_question as title , created_on as date FROM askquestions)) as a order by a.date desc;
```